# "SyntaxError: Invalid Syntax" from if__name__=='__main__'

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a climate control in Python via Raspberry Pi, but I'm getting an error:

```
traceback (most recent call last): if__name__=='__main__': syntaxerror: invalid syntax
```

Comment: In SO you have to provide a [mcve], there is no need to ask it, if you do not then your question will probably be closed as off-topic

Comment: We don't want the *whole* program; a [mcve] must be the shortest code that produces the same error when run. Similarly, if you can reproduce the same problem without a Raspberry Pi, then the fact that you're using a Raspberry Pi should not be included in the question.

Comment: That said, the obvious issue here is lack of spaces. You need to write `if __name__ == '__main__':` -- see the space between the `if` and the `__name__`, and between the `__name__` and the `=`.

Comment: change `if__name__=='__main__'` to `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Iam sorry.. have not used this forum before..

Comment: i will try that and return.. thanks

Comment: We're not a forum, we're a Q&A knowledgebase. Very different things -- the goal of a forum is to have somewhere you can ask peers for help when you need it. *That's not our goal*. Our goal is to build a database of unique programming questions and answers for each -- if we do the goal well, you can find your questions already asked and answered most of the time and only rarely need to ask something new. See also [The Wikipedia Of Long-Tail Programming Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/01/05/the-wikipedia-of-long-tail-programming-questions/), an early blog post from SO's founder.

Comment: ...that also explains why we're so picky about the quality of questions -- they don't need to just be good enough to help us help you (though that's important!), they also need to be good enough to help other people with the same problem (clearly written, without unnecessary details, with descriptive titles, etc)

Comment: yea sorry ill remember that

Answer (score 0):

*<sub>(This community-wiki answer is provided as an addendum/extension/context for the vote-to-close-as-typo).</sub>*

The following code reproduces your error:

```
if__name__=='__main__':
    pass
```

...and the following change fixes it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

If you don't have a space after `if`, it isn't parsed as a word in the language, but rather part of a single word `if__name__`.

Moreover, as a matter of good style, you should use whitespace *everywhere* [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) advises you to, which also includes surrounding the `==` sigil.